# Select minimum number in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a table with data like.

```
ItemCode
1000
1002
1003
1020
1060
```

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to get the minimum number (ItemCode) that is NOT in this table and it should be able to get the next lowest number once the previous minimum order ID has been inserted in the table but also skip the numbers that are already in the DB. I only want to get 1 result each time the query is run.

So, it should get `1001` as the first result based on the table above. Once the `ItemCode = 1001` has been inserted into the table, the next result it should get should be `1004` because `1000` to `1003` already exist in the table.

Based on everything I have seen online, I think, I have to use a While loop to do this. Here is my code which I'm still working on.

```
DECLARE @Count int
SET @Count= 0   
WHILE Exists (Select ItemCode
                from OITM
                where itemCode like '10%'
                AND convert(int,ItemCode) >= '1000'
                and convert(int,ItemCode) <= '1060')
        Begin
            SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1

            select MIN(ItemCode) + @Count
            from OITM
            where itemCode like '10%'
            AND convert(int,ItemCode) >= '1000'
            and convert(int,ItemCode) <= '1060'
        END
```

I feel like there has to be an easier way to accomplish this. Is there a way for me to say...

**select the minimum number between 1000 and 1060 that doesn't exist in table X**

EDIT: Creating a new table isn't an option in my case

Final Edit: Thanks guys! I got it. Here is my final query that returns exactly what I want. I knew I was making it too complicated for no reason!

```
With T0 as ( select convert(int,ItemCode) + row_number() over (order by convert(int,ItemCode)) as ItemCode
             from OITM
             where itemCode like '10%'
             AND convert(int,ItemCode) >= '1000'
             And convert(int,ItemCode) <= '1060')
Select MIN(convert(varchar,ItemCode)) as ItemCode
from T0
where convert(int,ItemCode) Not in (Select convert(int,ItemCode)
                                    from OITM
                                    where itemCode like '10%'
                                    AND convert(int,ItemCode) >= '1000'
                                    and convert(int,ItemCode) <= '1060');
```

Comment: you don't need to create a table, you can use a `CTE` or `sys.columns` as per the solution provided by wewesthemenace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the thing. Here you are generating sequantial number for rows, then comparing each row with next row(done by joining condition), and filtering those rows only where difference is not 1, ordering by sequence and finally picking the top most.

```
;with c as(select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn)
select top 1 c1.id + 1 as NewID
from c as c1
join c as c2 on c1.rn + 1 = c2.rn
where c2.id - c1.id <> 1
order by c1.rn
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `row_number()` to produce sequential values for each row, and then look for the first row where the `row_number()` doesn't match the value stored in the table. My SQL Server installation isn't working at the moment and SQL Fiddle seems to be down too, so I wrote this without being able to test it, but something like this should work:

```
declare @lowerBound int = 1000;
declare @upperBound int = 1060;

declare @x table ([id] int);
insert @x values (1000), (1002), (1003), (1020), (1060);

with [SequenceCTE] as
(
    select
        [id],
        [seq] = (@lowerBound - 1) + row_number() over (order by [id])
    from
        @x
)
select top 1
    [seq]
from
    [SequenceCTE]
where
    [seq] != [id] and
    [seq] <= @upperBound;
```

**EDIT:** [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uq4DVU20) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates this approach. I don't know why the site wasn't working for me before. It doesn't seem to like my `declare` statements for some reason so I hard-coded the bounds instead, but hopefully it still gets the idea across.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Tally Table. Check this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) by Jeff Moden for reference.

Basically, you want to generate numbers from `@start` to `@end`. That's where the Tally Table comes in. It will be used in the numbers generation. When you have your numbers, you just have to check for the minimum value that does not exist in your table.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be0a5/1/0)

```
DECLARE @start INT = 1000
DECLARE @end   INT = 1060

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
)
,E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@end - @start + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM E4
)
SELECT
    MIN(@start + t.N)
FROM Tally t
WHERE
    @start + t.N <= @end
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM OITM
        WHERE CAST(ItemCode AS INT) = @start + t.N
    )
```

---

Here is another query that uses `sys.columns` to generate the Tally Table:

```
;WITH Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@end - @start + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 1 
    FROM sys.columns a
    --CROSS JOIN sys.columns b
)
SELECT
    MIN(@start + t.N)
FROM Tally t
WHERE
    @start + t.N <= @end
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM OITM
        WHERE CAST(ItemCode AS INT) = @start + t.N
    )
```